Jenkins 'Rebuild' plugin doesn't rebuild files
I have a question:
I downloaded the 'Rebuild" plugin in jenkins in order to rebuild past builds.
Some of my pipelines have both string and file parameters as inputs.
For some reason, the file parameters i already uploaded in past builds don't reappear when i click the 'Rebuild' button (string ones do reappear).
Is there any solution to this?

Do you have https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/ installed by any chance?

I do not.
Does the rebuild plugin not work with files without this additional plugin?
